# Delay first request in webapi core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I test my API (read one string from db(redis) and De-serialize it ) by postman.

in first impact (every 1 min or other IP in same time) it return : 170ms
but from second and more :56ms

- it is not related startup application because it has traffic.
  I want find problem

because every new user open api in first time has more delay and then for go to other page it fast.

** this api run on IIS

Comment: Sounds like you have a 1 minute cache somewhere in your code (or a client-side cache configured for Redis)?

Comment: no i not have any config. for example if i send another request from other competer in 5 second after first one in my computer that has same problem . (first request from each device has delay (time is base on one device))

Comment: Does this apply if requests from other machines are _identical_ in all respects to the first request - i.e. same (entire) URL, same headers (including cookies)?

Comment: yes all are same and i did not any identical or first request

Comment: Try to add a timer to your Web API and record the time it takes to get the data in the first request and the second request. Besides, you could also refer [this article](http://www.schwammysays.net/auto-starting-websites-on-iis-7-5/) and configure the Auto-Start feature. And you can also check [Reducing initial request latency by pre-building services in a startup task in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/reducing-latency-by-pre-building-singletons-in-asp-net-core/).